# How to put NIC on different CPU socket?

Tags: cpu, nic, sockets

I want NICs in the different sockets, because for now I have NIC on the same CPU socket. Could you help me how to change it? I've attached how it looks like for now:

[image: NIC_the_same_CPU_socket]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put NIC on PCI and PCI-express socket

Comment: But I have only PCI-e on my server.. is there any possibility to change it from cli?

Comment: Just insert external LAN card on PCI-e port and disable onboard port from bios.